# Definite integral of trigonometric functions with complicated arguments

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions, integral-transforms

I came across beautiful integral (where $n$ is integer)

$I(n, z) = \int_0^{\pi} \cos(nx) \sin(z \cos(x) ) \mathrm{d}x $

According to Gradshteyn and Ryzhik (p 414, Sec. 3.715, Eq. 13), solution is with Bessel function:

$I(n, z) = \pi \sin(n \pi /2) J_n(z)$

How to proove beautiful result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For even $n$**, just do $x\mapsto x-\pi/2$ and use the fact that your integrand is becoming odd (and you integrate over the symmetric interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

**For odd $n$**, inserting $t=ie^{ix}$ into the generating function expansion
$$
e^{\frac{z}{2}(t-1/t)}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} J_k(z) t^k,
$$
we find the Fourier cosine series
$$
e^{iz\cos x}=J_0(z)+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}i^k J_k(z)\cos(kx).
$$
Take the imaginary part, and your integral formula is given by the formula for the Fourier coefficient.